# background-color transparent in css does not give proper layered layout

Tags: html, css

My code is as shown below:

xyz.css

```
.q-order-info-container {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent {
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
    height: 100px;
    padding: 0;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .status-background {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .status-background .status-bar-default {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: 2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: gray;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .status-background .status-bar-one-active {
    width: 50%;
    height: 2px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    background-color: #6900B2;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .status-background .status-bar-two-active {
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    height: 2px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    background-color: #6900B2;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    /* margin: 10px 10px 0 10px; */
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
    transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
    height: 100%;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-one {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-one .q-status-text {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #6900B2;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-two {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: white;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-two .q-status-text {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #6900B2;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-three {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    background-color: white;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-three .q-status-text {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #6900B2;
}
```

xyz.html

```
<div class="q-order-info-container">
    <div class="status-parent" ng-model="order" ng-switch="order.order_status">

        <div class="q-status-container">
            <div class="q-status-one">
                <div class="q-status-text"> 1</div>
            </div>
            <div class="q-status-two">
                <div class="q-status-text"> 2</div>
            </div>
            <div class="q-status-three">
                <div class="q-status-text"> 3</div>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="status-background">
            <div class="status-bar-default">
            </div>
            <div ng-switch-when="1" class="status-bar-one-active"></div>
            <div ng-switch-when="2" class="status-bar-two-active"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the output that I am getting is

[image]

But, I want the strip to be in the background of other thing like this

[image]

Comment: Make the lines shorter.

Comment: Even if I make the lines shorter , the line will be on the top for "2" status

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a working demo:

```css
.q-order-info-container {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent {
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 0;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .status-background {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .status-background .status-bar-default {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: 2px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .status-background .status-bar-one-active {
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  background-color: #6900B2;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .status-background .status-bar-two-active {
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  height: 2px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  background-color: #6900B2;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  /* margin: 10px 10px 0 10px; */
  box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.24);
  transition: all 0.3s cubic-bezier(.25, .8, .25, 1);
  height: 100%;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-one {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: white;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-one .q-status-text {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #6900B2;
  z-index: 10;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-two {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: white;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-two .q-status-text {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #6900B2;
  z-index: 10;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-three {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: white;
  padding-right: 10px;
}

.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-three .q-status-text {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  color: white;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 15px;
  background-color: #6900B2;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="q-order-info-container">
  <div class="status-parent" ng-model="order" ng-switch="order.order_status">

    <div class="q-status-container">
      <div class="q-status-one">
        <div class="q-status-text"> 1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="q-status-two">
        <div class="q-status-text"> 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="q-status-three">
        <div class="q-status-text"> 3</div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="status-background">
      <div class="status-bar-default">
      </div>
      <div ng-switch-when="1" class="status-bar-one-active"></div>
      <div ng-switch-when="2" class="status-bar-two-active"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You had to change the `z-index` on your numbers.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You need z-index property on your:

```
.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-two .q-status-text {
z-index:1
}
```

same thing for:

```
.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-one .q-status-text {
z-index: 1
}


.q-order-info-container .status-parent .q-status-container .q-status-three .q-status-text {
z-index:1
}
```